# Volume under $z=10x^2+5y^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

I have to find the volume under the surface
$$z=10x^2+5y^2$$
and above $z=0$ in the region bounded by the plans $y=x,y=2$ and $x=0$.

At first, I thought the volume was
$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{x}^{2}(10x^2+5y^2)dydx$$
but I plotted the surface in Geogebra, it seems the upper limit of $x$ is lower than $2$. How am I supposed to find the upper limit of $x$?

I also tried using polar coordinates
$$x=\frac{r\cos\theta}{\sqrt{10}},\quad y=\frac{r\sin\theta}{\sqrt{5}}$$
which implies
$$dxdy=\frac{r}{\sqrt{50}}drd\theta$$
with
$$\frac{\pi}{4}\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2},\quad 0\leq r\leq2$$
But I'm not sure about the interval of $r$.

Comment: This is volume under paraboloid surface bound by planes. Simplest is to use cartesian coordinates like what you have done in the first approach. Your limits are absolutely correct. See it as a prism bound by three given planes $x = 0, y = 2, x = y$ but $z$ is bound above by paraboloid and below by $z = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be\begin{align}\int_0^2\int_x^210x^2+5y^2\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx&=\int_0^2-\frac{5}{3} \left(7 x^3-12 x^2-8\right)\,\mathrm dx\\&=33+\frac13.\end{align}